# What time window does the data in AnalyserNode.getByteFrequencyData correspond to?

Tags: javascript, fft

I would like to capture fourier transform of a small time window (ie ~1 second).

```
let audioCtx = new AudioContext();
let analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser()
let buffer = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);

//given an audio stream 'stream'
let source = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);

setInterval(()=>{
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(buffer);
    //Do some analysis with buffer...
},1000)
```

Using WebAPI's AnalyserNode I can get fourier data in bins of width `44100/analyser.fftSize = 22050/analyser.frequencyBinCount`, allowing for specifying the resolution by setting `analyser.fftSize`. What is unclear to me from the documentation is how the time window is set.

From the [API](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#render-quantum):

> Rendering an audio graph is done in blocks of 128 samples-frames. A block of 128 samples-frames is called a render quantum, and the render quantum size is 128.

Does this imply a time window of `128/44100Hz=2.9ms`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > Rendering an audio graph is done in blocks of 128 samples-frames. A block of 128 samples-frames is called a render quantum, and the render quantum size is 128.
>
> Does this imply a time window of 128/44100Hz=2.9ms?

Not quite. The render quantum size is the number of sample frames that gets processed at a time by the render loop, but it does not prevent nodes from accumulating additional samples in buffers. In the particular case of the `AnalyserNode`, the last `fftSize` samples are kept for the FFT computation. So the time window is effectively `analyser.fftSize/sampleRate`, where `sampleRate` is your [configured sample rate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContextOptions/sampleRate) (which may be 44100, but could vary depending on the output device). To capture ~1 second of audio, assuming a sampling rate of 44100Hz you would thus need `fftSize = 32768` (which would result in a time window of ~0.74 second).

Comment: How is this affected by [AnalyserNode.SmoothingTimeConstant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode/smoothingTimeConstant)? If it is set to 0, for `fftSize=32768`, then is the fft value solely determined by the last 0.74 seconds?

Comment: Indeed setting the `SmoothingTimeConstant` to 0 with `fftSize=32768` will produce results determined only by the last 0.74s. With values greater than 0, you get an average over FFT blocks, with reducing contributions from older blocks. For example with the time constant set to 0.607, you get an average that's mostly affected by the last ~10 FFT blocks (so reducing the `fftSize` to 4096 would give you a smoothing of FFTs spanning about 0.925s). I often use the rule of thumb of `exp(-5/N)` (where `N` is the approximate number of smoothed blocks) as the smoothing factor.